# Как верстать большой макет?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

PSD макет шириной 3360px, как его верстать? У меня монитор 1280px. Соответственно когда беру размеры шрифта, отступы и т.д, они слишком большие.  На одном форуме уже узнавал и мне посоветовали верстать с горизонтальной прокруткой. Хочется знать, что делают профессионалы в таком случае.

Answer (score 2):

зажми `ctrl` и крути колесо на себя, измениться масштаб окна и будет видно твои 3к,

ты главное шрифты укажи в `body`,`html`  в `vw`, а во всем остальном в `em` и будет счастье)

Comment: Так все и делают?